# How to arrange values in ascnding order when single row is present

Tags: sql-server-2005

How to arrange values in ascnding order when single row is there...i mean i have only one row in my table
for example

prashanth  6   1   3   2   4  5 ...can we annage these velues in ascending order?...
only one row is in the table.row number is 1....and we have 6 columns how can we arrange in ascending order..the values should come like this 6 5 4 3 2 1..
i mean that the row values should be in a particular order....when we have one row the row values should be in particular order..... that's what i am asking

Comment: Is there is only ever one row in the table? If so then perhaps you could change the table schema to a key/value pairing with your columns represented as values and a sort order. Sorting can then be done with an order by on the sort column.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one row, what is there to sort?

When selecting several rows, you can use an [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) clause to sort them:

```
SELECT myFirstColumn, mySecondColumn
FROM myTable
ORDER BY mySecondColumn
```

If you want the columns in a specific order, when writing your select statement simply state the columns in the order you want:

```
SELECT myFirstColumn, mySecondColumn
FROM myTable
```